# How to use instance methods among themselves in a javascript class

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inner-classes

I created an class in which I want to calculate the HEX color value based at the R G B color values which should be calculated first in the given class. I had no problem to do it at a function but wanted to check if I can do it also at a class.

My motive is to calculate at the end the HSL color value and from that been able run several instances of the class to show different nuances of a random created color.

Basically I want to know how it is possible to use the `rgb()` instance method values in the `hex()` instance method.

Here is the code at codepen:

```
https://codepen.io/buzzer79/pen/LJVxmP/
```

Also I copy it here:

```
class Colors {
  constructor(R, G, B, H, E, X) {
    this.R = R;
    this.G = G;
    this.B = B;
    this.H = H;
    this.E = E;
    this.X = X;
  }

  rgb() {
    //calculate RGB
    this.R = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    this.G = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    this.B = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

    return this.R + "," + this.G + "," + this.B;
  }

  hex() {
    //calcuate hex
    this.H =
      this.R.toString(16).length < 2
        ? "0" + this.R.toString(16)
        : this.R.toString(16);
    this.E =
      this.G.toString(16).length < 2
        ? "0" + this.G.toString(16)
        : this.G.toString(16);
    this.X =
      this.B.toString(16).length < 2
        ? "0" + this.B.toString(16)
        : this.B.toString(16);
    // return this.H+''+this.E+''+this.X;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `this.` to access instance properties.

Comment: Your constructor doesn't really make much sense. Also you should not store the color values twice - store the color once (in a canonical format) and derive the others as getters.

Comment: "HEX" is not a color format. It's a number formatting, used (amongst others) for the RGB numbers.